# SQL Count Records Held in All-time Records from a personal best table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have got a Personal best table that holds fishing weight personal best records for each named fish. These fall under a particular species.

SO far I have managed to pull in the all time records for each named fish, grouped by the species.

What I am trying to do now is set up a statistics page that shows various info, and one being how many (count) all time records are held by the selected Fisherman.

I have a selector so you can choose the name to bring up the statistics, and this is working fine.

I can't seem to count selected all-time records by a selected fisherman.

I have tried nesting Select statements but to no conclusion. I am pretty new to this stuff also.

This is my starter code with the field names in question.

```sql
SELECT Specie, NameFish, Contender, MAX(Drams) FROM PB_Scores GROUP BY NameFish
```

and lets say the table is…

```
SPECIE - NAMEFISH - CONTENDER - DRAMS

Tench  | Barry    | Jonhson   | 234
Pike   | Glub     | Johnson   | 3456
Pike   | Blake    | Johnson   | 4567
Pike   | Blake    | Mitchell  | 4890
Pike   | Glub     | Mitchell  | 0 
Tench  | Barry    | Mitchell  | 2420
```

The result for selecting Mitchell should then be:-

2 (because Mitchell has got Barry and Blake at bigger weights so the count is 2).

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a sub query to get the max weight for each species / name of fish, then joining that back to the table to get the contenders who have a fish of that species / name and weight:-

```
SELECT a.Contender, COUNT(*)
FROM PB_Scores a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Specie, NameFish, MAX(Drams) AS MaxSpeciesWeight
    FROM PB_Scores
    GROUP BY Specie, NameFish
) b
ON a.Specie = b.Specie
AND a.NameFish = b.NameFish
AND a.Drams = b.MaxSpeciesWeight
GROUP BY a.Contender
```

SQL fiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/966bf/1

Note this might give odd results if 2 people have both caught a fish of the same species, name and weight.

Comment: Brilliant. Can you suggest a way in which the code can list the shared records?

Comment: I have now added a piece of code after 'FROM PB_Score" to ignore any record with a zero. "WHERE Drams > 0"

Comment: With a shared record, both would be counted. Not sure if this is what you require. For example you might also have a date on the table and only want to count the record weight that occurs first. That where clause should work in the sub query to remove those with a zero weight.